# Hide Element in JQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery

Iam loading the content for an JQuery Dialog with dialog.load(''); now i want to hide some elements after the content is fetched. But the Element does not hide (-: Here is the part of the code:

```
.dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            title: 'Edit user account',
            width: 450,
            height: 350,
            open: function() {
                $('#password-label').hide();
            },
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *When* is the content loaded?

Comment: on click after the dialog is created, but it is realy an timing problem like basiclife told..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your open event is firing before the content has fully loaded. As a test, add a delay...

```
        open: function() {
            setTimeout('$(\'#password-label\').hide();', 1000);
        }
```

If that works, you need to find a trigger that can be used to determine when the content has finished loading - perhaps JS in the dialog content itself?